# iPhone UIAutomation:can't find sub-element of tableview

Tags: ios, ios-ui-automation, xcode-instruments

I have a view hierarchy as below:

```
-UIScrollView
--UITableView
---UIView
```

all of my code in project is:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

UIScrollView *scrollView = [[UIScrollView alloc] initWithFrame:self.view.bounds];
[self.view addSubview:scrollView];

UITableView *tableView = [[UITableView alloc] initWithFrame:scrollView.bounds];
tableView.delegate = self;
tableView.dataSource = self;
[scrollView addSubview:tableView];

UIView *tableSubView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 20)];
[tableView addSubview:tableSubView];
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {
return 3;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
static NSString *idForCell = @"id";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:idForCell];
if (!cell) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:idForCell];
}
cell.textLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",@(indexPath.row)];
return cell;
}
```

and my js code in Automation is:

```
var target = UIATarget.localTarget();
target.delay(2);
target.logElementTree();
```

finally I check element tree show in Trace Log by instruments,and the result is:

```
-UIATarget
--UIAApplication
---UIAWindow
----UIAScrollView
-----UIATableView
------UIATableCell
------UIATableCell
------UIATableCell
```

but I can't find the `tableSubView` element, can anyone tell me the reason?TKS very much!

Answer (score 0):

Try changing line

```
[tableView addSubview:tableSubView];
```

to

```
[tableView.superview addSubview:tableSubView];
```

Answer (score 0):

Sometimes, UIAutomation with Instruments is a little bit tricky. You can try several things,before calling `target.logElementTree();`:

- Make scrollToVisible() to the tableView

  `target.mainWindow().scrollViews()[0].tableViews()[0].scrollToVisible()`;
- Add accesibility Label to the table subview. In your code:

  `UIView *tableSubView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.bounds.size.width, 20)];
  tableSubView.accessibilityLabel = @"tableSubview";`

You can combine both. I hope this will help you!